# Calculate price of multiple items knowing its total sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I have here simple problem, but not having done any of this kind of math for long time, have got me in unpleasant situation.

Let's say that we have grocery store and three customers. Customer U,W and Z.

All of them bought the same type of products, but in different quantities and all we know is total price of those products. But not for customer Z.

How to calculate total price of customer Z purchase?

Customer U purchase: $$36(apples)+18(oranges)+27(pomegranates)=$477 $$
Customer W purchase: $$9(apples)+27(oranges)+18(pomegranates)=$432 $$
Customer Z purchase: $$1(apples)+1(oranges)+1(pomegranates)=$X $$

Comment: Generally speaking, you need three equations to specify three unknowns.  Your system does not have a unique solution.

Comment: Under the current formulation, this problem has multiple solutions.

Comment: ok, I made it more detailed. @mlc can you share one of the solutions ideas with which you came up?

Comment: This is bizarre. You have chosen a third equation whose LHS makes the system linearly dependent. The probability that this happens by chance is (theoretically) negligible. Either you are pulling our leg or you need to clarify the context of your question. (Currenlty, your system of equation has a solution only if $X=101/5$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this system does not have a unique solution. It has an infinite number of solutions. This is due to the fact that we have two definite equations, but three unknowns (i.e., only the first two equations can be considered since we know nothing about the third equation).

Let's convert the system into symbols and we'll see why: $$\begin{cases}36a+18o+27p = 477\\9a+27o+18p=432.\end{cases}$$ Let's multiply the $2^{nd}$ equation by $4$ to give us $$\begin{cases}36a+18o+27p = 477\\36a+108o+72p=1728.\end{cases}$$ I will then rearrange the $2^{nd}$ equation like so: $$\begin{cases}36a+18o+27p = 477\\36a=1728 -108o-72p.\end{cases}$$ So I know what $36a$ is, which I will replace the $36a$ in the first equation with the second equation: $$\underbrace{(1728-108o-72p)}_{36a} + 18o+27p=477,$$ which if I combine like terms and divide out any common factors, I get: $$10o+5p=139.$$ So I have managed to reduce the system to a two variable equation, but I don't have any other equations to reduce it to just one variable, which we know how to solve for a definite answer using basic algebra. I can't use the third equation because this introduces another variable, $X$. Even if, we'd still end up with this problem of too many variables and not enough information.

So, the only thing that we can do is pick any random number for one of the variables and gain a solution that way (again, we don't have enough information, so the only thing we can do is just make it up ourselves).

So maybe pomegranates are $\$1.98$ each. Then, I just plug this into the above equation, $$10o+5(1.98)=139,$$ and I get that oranges are $o=\$12.98$. (which is pretty expensive for an orange!). Then I use this information in the equation $$\begin{align}36a & =1728 -108o-72p\\ &= 1728 - 108(12.98)-72(1.98)\\ &= 183.60,\end{align}$$ which tells us $$36a = 183.60,$$ or when we divide by $36$, which is $a=\$30.60$. So this is a solution. A pretty bad one at that, but again we don't have enough information to really find an answer other than just making one up. ([you can read about this concept here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system)). I understand the concept of "making up an answer" will make less mathematically mature students cringe because it just sounds like something you'd get points taken off for on homework or an exam, but introducing a "free-variable" into systems with too many unknowns is pretty common practice in many real-world scenarios (the GPS on your phone or in your car being one of them).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!